# Border transition is working to the right, but not to the left

Tags: html, css, radio-button, css-transitions

I have six separate options. I want the black border to slide left and right smoothly on clicking any of the options. When I click on “Service Providers”, the black bottom border must slide smoothly towards right. When I click on “Friends”, it should slide smoothly towards left. I want to achieve this with CSS transitions. It is working fine when I click the option on the right, but the left transition is not working.

```css
.row {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  margin: 0px;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 16.33%;
  border-bottom: 2px black solid;
  transition: all .5s;
}

#friendBox:checked~span {
  left: 0%;
}

#sellerBox:checked~span {
  left: 16.33%;
}

#familyBox:checked~span {
  left: 33.33%;
}

#clientsBox:checked~span {
  left: 50%;
}

#childrenBox:checked~span {
  left: 67%;
}

#elderBox:checked~span {
  left: 83.75%;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <input type="radio" id="friendBox"></input>
      <input type="radio" id="sellerBox"></input>
      <input type="radio" id="familyBox"></input>
      <input type="radio" id="clientsBox"></input>
      <input type="radio" id="childrenBox"></input>
      <input type="radio" id="elderBox"></input>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label for="friendBox">Friends</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label for="sellerBox">Service Providers</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label for="familyBox">Family</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label for="clientsBox">Clients</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label for="childrenBox">Children</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label for="elderBox">Elders</label>
      </div>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You don’t use radio buttons correctly.
The purpose of radio buttons is to have at most one radio button active among a group of radio buttons.
The six radio buttons you have are independent from each other, so toggling one doesn’t toggle the existing active one.

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#defining_a_radio_group).
You need to use the same `name` for all six radio buttons.
Since they define your menu, let’s call it `name="menu"`.

Another thing: `</input>` isn’t valid; remove it.

Another suggestion: your `<label>`s don’t fill the entire height of the menu item; replace the `<div>`s by the `<label>`s directly.
They still appear to have some bottom margin, but I’m sure you can find another solution for this.

```css
.row {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  margin: 0px;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 16.33%;
  border-bottom: 2px black solid;
  transition: all .5s;
}

#friendBox:checked~span {
  left: 0%;
}

#sellerBox:checked~span {
  left: 16.33%;
}

#familyBox:checked~span {
  left: 33.33%;
}

#clientsBox:checked~span {
  left: 50%;
}

#childrenBox:checked~span {
  left: 67%;
}

#elderBox:checked~span {
  left: 83.75%;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <input id="friendBox" type="radio" name="menu">
      <input id="sellerBox" type="radio" name="menu">
      <input id="familyBox" type="radio" name="menu">
      <input id="clientsBox" type="radio" name="menu">
      <input id="childrenBox" type="radio" name="menu">
      <input id="elderBox" type="radio" name="menu">
      <label class="col-sm-2" for="friendBox">Friends</label>
      <label class="col-sm-2" for="sellerBox">Service Providers</label>
      <label class="col-sm-2" for="familyBox">Family</label>
      <label class="col-sm-2" for="clientsBox">Clients</label>
      <label class="col-sm-2" for="childrenBox">Children</label>
      <label class="col-sm-2" for="elderBox">Elders</label>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```